# На отрезке [100, N] (210 < N < 231) найти количество чисел, составленных из цифр а, b, с

Tags: python, функции

Мой код

```
N = int(input("Введите правую границу отрезка N,(210 < N < 231): "))
print("Введите a, b и с: ")
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
def func(v):
    x = v // 100
    y = (v % 100) // 10
    z = (v % 100) % 10
    if (x == a) or (x == b) or (x == c):
        if (y == a) or (y == b) or (y == c):
            if (z == a) or (z == b) or (z == c):
                print(x, y, z)
for i in range(100, N):
    func(i)
print(k)
if k == 0:
    print("Ошибка. Числа, состоящие из ", a," ", b, " ", c, " Отсуствуют. Попробуйте снова")
```

Не могу только подсчитывать эти числа.Что мне нужно сделать.

Comment: вывести можете, а подсчитать - нет, как так?

Comment: верните из функции результат-то, подходит число или нет. и плюсуйте его к счетчику.

Comment: а-ля `while($n >= 100) $result += func($n--)`, не знаю как это будет на питоне

Comment: `k = sum(func(i) for i in range(100, N))`

Comment: @teran не вам отправил, извините. Как мне вернуть результат в функции?

Comment: @teran все, я разобрался. Без вашей помощи не понял бы, спасибо большое

Comment: Проверка написана правильно, но ее можно сильно подсократить, если использовать множества (`set`), надо проверить только одно условие `if {a, b, c} >= {x, y, z}:` Первое множество можно присвоить какой-то  переменной до цикла.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import permutations

N = int(input())
a, b, c = input(), input(), input()
for chance in permutations([a,b,c]):
    if 100 >= int(''.join(chance)) < N:
        print(''.join(chance))
```

В начале мы принимаем на вход N, а потом три числа (строковым типом данных). Для перебора всех возможных вариантов я использовал библиотеку *itertools* и её модуль *permutations*. При переборе элементов я просто проверяю вхождение получившегося числа на искомый отрезок, а затем вывожу его

Comment: Хорошо ли вы поняли задачу? Проверяли ли свой код?

Comment: @MBo Наверное, `product` нужен тогда или ещё что-то не то?

Comment: @CrazyElf Ну с неравенством ладно, описка, но не учитывается, что цифры могут повторяться - да, наверное, product можно использовать